# Spring resttemplate expose what services are available

Tags: spring, resttemplate

Is there a way I can create a list of what controllers I have exposed in spring rest template? I'd like to have a service that holds the information about what is exposed right now.

Like right now, I'm looking into creating a method that finds all annotated methods of RequestMapping.class, but I'd rather use something that is common.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Swagger and SwaggerUI if You want some basic user interface for that exposed endpoint's as well.

Another library that came to my mind, is Hystrix (from Netflix), it can handle service unavailability (so it can be used to monitor exposed services) and it also has a dashboard.

Comment: Using hystrix will be a bit more of a rewrite :) We do however use netflix servo that is part of hystrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Spring Boot Application - you can use [Spring Actuator](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-boot-actuator/) for this purpose.

Comment: This isn't a spring boot application :/